Why is my generateToken() function not working?
I have created a social media page for my coursework. I have a login page and a home page. Once logged in the user is redirected to the home page, which all works fine. As soon as I add in my generateToken() function, it stops being redirected. I have never posted on here before so sorry if i've not been very clear
PHP:
functions.php
function generateRandomString($length) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    $max = strlen ($characters) - 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters [rand (0, $max)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function generateToken () {
    $_SESSION['token'] = generateRandomString(20);
}

function validateToken ($formToken){
    if($formToken === $_SESSION['token']){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

login.php
<?php
session_start();

include("connection.php");
include("functions.php");

// Generate CSRF token on page load
generateToken();

// Check if the form is submitted and the CSRF token is valid
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['token']) && validateToken($_POST['token'])) {

// Get user input
    $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];
    $userPassword = $_POST['userPassword'];

    // Check if email and password are not empty
    if (!empty($userEmail) && !empty($userPassword)) {
        // Prepare SQL statement
        $sqlQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userEmail = ? LIMIT 1");
        $sqlQuery->bind_param("s", $userEmail);
        
        if ($sqlQuery->execute()) {
            $result = $sqlQuery->get_result();
            $user_data = $result->fetch_assoc(); // Fetch data as associative array
            
            // Check if user exists and password matches
            if ($user_data && password_verify($userPassword, $user_data['userPassword'])) {
                // Log in the user
                $_SESSION['userID'] = $user_data['userID'];
                header("Location: home_page.html");
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

Form section of HTML:
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="userEmail" required>Email Address</label>
       <input type="email" name="userEmail" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="userPassword">Password</label>
       <input type="password" name="userPassword" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
 </form>


I tried removing the generateToken function and was able to 'login' and be redirected to my home page, so it must be something in the generateToken function that is stopping it.
When the function is added, the page just looks like it refreshes and removes the inputs within the fields, and does not redirect or login

Because you're generating the token also inside the post page, overriding the previous value.
For a fast solution, move the generateToken(); call after the if block.

Try using this $_SESSION['token'] = generateRandomString(20); directly instead of creating and calling a function.

Not directly related to your problem, but debugging things with redirects can be a pain. Until you have things working perfect, sometimes it is easier to just echo "success" and "fail", because then you can also see potential warning messages, too. Also, you have a semi-deep nested if, with a lot of missing else statements that I would strongly recommend having. Actually, I'd recommend inverting most of it and using a pattern called "return early". Lastly, you are redirecting to an HTML page, so I just want to make sure you understand that sessions won't be honored on it.
